# When I destruct record, can I make a hypothesis name without 0?

Tags: coq

I made such record.

```
Record dlos := mkdlos { 
  X : Type; 
  Xlt : relation X;
  Xeq : relation X; 
  eq : equivalence Xeq;
  st : strict_order Xlt;
  to : total_order Xlt Xeq;
  den : dense Xlt;
}.
```

For example, if I wrote such code,

```
Example exists_0 (S : dlos) : 
True. 
Proof. 
destruct S.
```

then I saw this window.

```
1 goal
X0 : Type
Xlt0, Xeq0 : relation X0
eq0 : equivalence Xeq0
st0 : strict_order Xlt0
to0 : total_order Xlt0 Xeq0
den0 : dense Xlt0
______________________________________(1/1)
True
```

I want to erase all of 0 by default.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will give you explicit names:

```ml
Record dlos := mkdlos { 
  X : Type; 
  x: X;
}.

Example exists_0 (S : dlos) : 
True. 
Proof. 
destruct S as [X x].
```

or if you are going to be destructing the record a lot of times, you can define a new tactic:

```ml
Ltac destruct_dlos S := destruct S as [X x] || destruct S.

Example exists_0 (S : dlos) (R : dlos): 
True. 
Proof. 
destruct_dlos S.
destruct_dlos R.
```

Note that the above definition will switch to a regular `destruct` where Coq chooses the names if the explicit destruct fails.

Generally speaking, the `as ...` part of a tactic lets you provide explicit names, with `as [a b c...]` naming products (pairs, records) and `as [a|b|...]` naming sums (inductive data).

Comment: I know your suggested way. By the way, I might use this 'dlos' a hundreds of times, and every time I write 'as...' seems not so good. (Moreover, since the number of my components of dlos is many, if I write 'as ... ' then it possesses many spaces. ) Thus I share my question.

Comment: You can define a new tactic to prevent retyping out the syntax: `Ltac destruct_dlos S := destruct S as [X x].`

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth having a look at Pierre Courtieu's LibHyps library, which allows you to control the new hypotheses generated by a tactic.

https://github.com/Matafou/LibHyps